# How to upload a pdf file to any information page in opencart2?

Tags: php, pdf, upload, opencart, opencart2.x

I need to find a way to upload a pdf file to my terms & services page in opencart2. I've looked for an extention, but the suitable extentsion are for opencart 1.5.x.

Is there a way to upload a pdf file and make it downloadable on the information page?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to upload the file using FTP to a location within your website (e.g. the `downloads` subdirectory), then put a link to it on the information page using the information page editor. (e.g. `http://www.tuinenmetgevoel.nl/downloads/myfile.pdf`)

Comment: Hmm yes, that could be the solution, but some people in my company don't know much about ftp, but I can do that for them on this page. Opencart is not really 'user friendly' unfortunately.

Comment: @KeesSonnema : you can create custom module to upload pdf under folder `download` or `images`.

Comment: Yes, will leave it like this, but it's an idea :) Can always try.